# How can I get the relationship between start node and end node?

Tags: graph, neo4j

I'm trying to find family relations.

For example I want to know what's the relation between me and my father's wife? It should return mother.

What's the relation between me and my mother's daughter? It should return sister.

This is what my graph looks like. There are 8 relations and 2 labels (Male or Female).

[image: My graph]

How can I achieve this without specifying any node? For example if I want to know the relation between me and my father's daughter.

I want to do something like `MATCH () -[:Father]->()-[:Daughter]->()` and relationship between start and end node.

I'm sure this query is absolutely wrong but I hope you get an idea what I'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: You can't match a relation without any node, I mean if you want to know the relation between you and your father's daugther, you have to use the node that referees to you (or to your father's daughter). Else you will match every relationship names "Father" of "Daughter"

Comment: But every relation will return the same value, right? So not really a problem.

Comment: I don't understand your question so ^^"

Comment: @Supamiu Is there a way to get all the `() -[:Father]->()-[:Daughter]->()` nodes that match this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So,

At first - you should always specify some nodes.

Let's create some data:

```
CREATE (me:Person)
CREATE (mother:Person)
CREATE (daughter:Person)
CREATE (me)-[:Son]->(mother)
CREATE (me)<-[:Mother]-(mother)
CREATE (me)-[:Brother]->(daughter)
CREATE (me)<-[:Sister]-(daughter)
CREATE (mother)-[:Mother]->(daughter)
CREATE (mother)<-[:Daughter]-(daughter)
```

[image: data]

---

> What's the relation between me and my mother's daughter? It should return sister.

Now we can find anwser to your question:

```
MATCH (me)<-[:Mother]-()<-[:Daughter]-(she)
MATCH (me)<-[r]-(she)
RETURN type(r)
```

Result:

```
Sister
```

What we have been done:

- First match: specify starting path
- Second match: ask for desired path
- Return: get path results

---

> For example I want to know what's the relation between me and my father's wife? It should return mother.

Here something like this should work:

```
MATCH (me)<-[:Father]-()<-[:Wife]-(she)
MATCH (me)<-[r]-(she)
RETURN type(r)
```

Result:

```
Mother
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) Just one question though. Why does it return it `n` times? Where `n` is number of relationships.

Comment: When you specify `MATCH (me)<-[r]-(she)` - it means that you want **all** relationships between those 2 nodes.  So, you'll receive all relationship between those nodes.

If you want to get specific relationship - then you should somehow narrow your query.

Comment: Oh, never mind. I had duplicate data in my database. So that's why it was returning more than one. Thanks.